# Callback after success and data changed

Tags: react-query

I used the `onSuccess` callback, but it is called every time the data is successfully retrieved.

I expect to be called only when the data changed(deep equal). Is there any good way to do this?

```
useQuery(..., {
  onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
})

// first: [1], second: [2], // => call
// first: [1], second: [1], // => not call
```

How to do this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onSuccess is tied to successful data fetching. If you want to spawn a side-effect whenever data changes, use a useEffect:

```
const { data } = useQuery(...)
useEffect(() => ..., [data])
```

Comment: Don’t forget to memorize the `select` and don't ask me what i went through

Comment: you can inline the select function. the only difference is that it will run on every render. The result will still be structurally shared for referential stability. Unless your select function is very expensive, it shouldn't matter if you memoize it or not.

Comment: This means, inline select, the data will also not change? So is this a bug after v3.34.7? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-dawn-jilgs?file=/src/index.js) [#3140](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/pull/3140)

Comment: yes, looks like it. it works fine in 3.34.6. can you file an issue please?

Comment: yes, I will open an issue

Comment: for posterity: the issue has been fixed in v3.34.8: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/releases/tag/v3.34.8